# List of official anime releases

Tags: resources

I want to find a regularly updated list of official anime home video releases (ie DVD/BluRay/digital), English dubbed/subtitled and available globally, preferably sorted by date of release. Does such a thing exist?

If it was part of a larger list of non-anime home video releases that is fine. Wikipedia has lists such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_in_home_video), but they do not seem to contain releases from smaller studios.

Comment: I use [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) by searching for the series and see if it has a licences in english, if it's streaming it'll list it in brackets however i have to search for series title itself and it wont be updated if a series has been discontinued (ie. Robotech The Shadow Chronicles while released on DVD in Australia by Madman is now discontinued so you can't buy it from them, likewise with the second Negima anime)

Comment: Are you asking about release dates in Japan, or licensed releases in another country, or all licensed release dates worldwide?

Comment: @seijitsu thx, for English speakers & available globally, I clarified that now in the question.

Comment: @Memor-X wow their Upcoming video list (http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/releases.php?format=video) is very close to what I wanted, that could be the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/) by searching for a series i'm interested in and seeing if it has a licences for english, this can normally be found further down a page where it lists who does the translations and Voice Actors if it was dubbed. it would also list distributors and internet streamers (like Crunchyroll).

However there seems to be a list for upcoming home releases [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/releases.php?format=video), i can validate the Kill la Kill release with a recent Madman email advertising it's release in Australia. However credit should go to [this comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14615/list-of-official-anime-releases?noredirect=1#comment18999_14615) as i actually didn't know about the list on Anime News Network.

with the list if you click on the DVD you want then scroll down to the encyclopedia link and scroll down the next page to "English companies" you can see who the distributors are and to what context their releases where (if they are iternet streaming, subtitled, if it has an English cast then it's been dubbed)